# List custom changes made to Android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to make a "diff" to extract custom changes made by a consultant on Android source code. I know that the branch on which changes have been made is 4.2.2_r1 (build id JDQ39) but a raw "diff -r" lists over 60k files changed.

How can I know the exact source code "commit" (or whatever is called in repo) to make the diff more accurate and replicate changes on the original Android source code?

Thanks, regards.

Comment: Take a look at www.grepcode.com. It provides Android source code, with diffs per file per version.

Comment: sorry, I didn't specify but I mean *custom* changes: an external consultant made custom changes that I need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to the Android Source code can be tracked down efficently by using the [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) command. Checkout all the repositories to the branch 4.2.2_r1 and use command `repo forall -vc "pwd && git diff"` or `repo diff`.

FYI- Instead of `git diff` in `repo forall -vc "pwd && git diff"` you can use other git commands. example:- `repo forall -vc "pwd && git status"`. Checking out all repositories to a particular branch can also be done using `repo forall -vc "pwd && git checkout <branch-name>"`

Note: `pwd && git <command>` prints the absolute path first and then execute the git command. This is to format the output as repository path followed by its git command result.